# Python read csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, readfile

Help me! This is the error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6e197d6c2788> in <module>()
      2   csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
      3 
----> 4   for i in csv_reader:
      5     print(i)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

Here is the Code that is causing this:

```
import csv
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

  for i in csv_reader:
    print(i)
```

Comment: why don't you use pandas.read_csv ??

Comment: When I use pandas it too

Comment: Please check the CSV file and see what is actually in that line with something like Excel

Comment: I've had this before. This usually happens when you are either decoding with the wrong thing (ex: UTF8 vs UTF16) or you have characters in the CSV the decoder doesn't know how to interpret. Or at least those are the two scenarios in which I've received the error.

Comment: Can you please paste output of `locale` command, try to run `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and re-run your code.

Comment: Try first using [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) to guess the encoding and then add that encoding when opening the file